# android - webview content shows very bad

Tags: android, android-webview

this is my code for making the webview , it shows the content very small and in a very bad shape .I'm pretty sure that the html is correct ,the font-size is good , the content take the whole width in the browser but in the webview it shows like this :

[image]

as you can see, it takes about 1/3 of the width , the font-size is very small.

this is my webview code:

```
WebView webview = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.wb);
                    webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
                    webview.getSettings().setSupportZoom(false);
                    webview.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
                    WebSettings settings = webview.getSettings();
                    settings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
                    settings.setAppCacheEnabled(false);
                    settings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);

                    webview.loadDataWithBaseURL("",body, "text/html", "UTF-8", "");
```

could you help me ? what is the problem ?